# RabbitMQ in Docker throws exception when I try to connect from java with custom port

Tags: java, docker, rabbitmq

I run RabbitMQ in docker using this command:

```
docker run --rm -it --hostname my-rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

It works and I can connect to RabitMq from java:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setUsername("guest");
factory.setPassword("guest");
Connection connection = factory.newConnection("http://localhost:5672");
```

But I need to change port and I do this:

```
docker run --rm -it --hostname my-rabbit -p 15673:15672 -p 5673:5672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

When I open http://localhost:15673/ - it works. I see the admin console. But when I try to connect

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setUsername("guest");
    factory.setPassword("guest");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection("http://localhost:5673");
```

I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:81)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:162)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:59)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:63)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:160)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1216)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1173)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1310)
    at com.project.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

[image]

EDIT: When I use port 5672 without changes I see this (maybe it can help)
[image]

Comment: Did you follow the steps given https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/ ? setting users/passwords, management plugins etc?

Comment: @
Sachith Muhandiram Yes, it works with guest/guest on 5672 and 15672 and it works with changed 15673 but doesn't work with changed 5673. I don't touch anything except ports mapping

Answer (score 2):

I changed the code to this and it works. Thanks, RabbitMQ for so obvious code!

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setPort(5673);
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    factory.setUsername("guest");
    factory.setPassword("guest");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an HTTP URI - `http://localhost:5673`

You should be using an AMQP URI - `amqp://localhost:5673`

I'm kind of surprised the first one worked at all, without a parsing error. My guess is that since the scheme (`http`) was not correct, the client used the default of `localhost:5672`.

AMQP URIs are documented here - https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html